# MVC5(Asp.Net4.5.2)- RedirectToAction não funciona em um caso único

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

No meu controlador Account, na Ação Login, tenho o código abaixo:

```
                case "Sucess":
                    string rule = CheckRule(model.username, model.Password);
                    Response.SetCookie(SetAuthCookie(model.username, model.RememberMe, rule));
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", rule);
```

No checkrule, eu retorno uma string com o nome do controlador de acordo com a regra de autenticação, entre estes nomes estão Admin e BasicUser, abaixo está o código destes controladores:

Admin

```
{
[Authorize]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private bool attAuthor = isAuthorized();
    private bool attAuth = isAuthenticated();
    private string rule = returnrule();
    // GET: Admin
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (!attAuthor)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("erro401",rule);
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }


    }

    public ActionResult erro401()
    {
        return View("erro401");
    }
```

}

e BasicUser:

```
{
[Authorize]
public class BasicUserController : Controller
{
    private bool attAuthor = isAuthorized();
    private bool attAuth = isAuthenticated();
    private string rule = returnrule();
    // GET: BasicUser
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         if (!attAuthor)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("erro401", rule);
        }
        else
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authticket = get_ticket();
            string str = rule + " / " + authticket.Name;
            ViewBag.Htmlstr = str;
            return View();
        }


    }

    public ActionResult erro401()
    {
        return View("erro401");
    }


}
```

}

No código do Route config:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "",
           defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "BasicUser",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "BasicUser", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Admin",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
```

Se eu me logar com usuário Admin funciona , mas se eu me logar com um basicuser o navegador não redireciona, simplesmente fica na tela de logon, porem se eu digitar na barra de endereços ele vai para a página certa.
Eu adicionei uma tag no Index.cshtml do basicuser para ver a regra que aparece no cookie, e aparece a regra certa, só não esta redirecionando para a pagina do controlador .

Desculpe se não fui muito claro, sou muito newbie ainda...

Answer (score 2):

Ei pessoal fia a mesma pergunta no Stack em Inglês, já recebi a resposta e obtive êxito na correção deste erro:
Meu problema estava na configuração das rotas eu refiz as rotas com o código abaixo:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "BasicUser",
                url: "BasicUser/{action}/",
                defaults: new { controller = "BasicUser", action = "Index" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Admin",
                 url: "Admin/{action}/",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index"}
             );
```

O padrão de url estava `"/{controller}/{action}/"` agora eu aponto diretamente para o controller. Certo é que preciso estudar mais essa questão de rotas antes de por isto em produção, não quero ficar exposto a falhas...

Comment: Segue o link com as repostas da questão em inglês: [Resposta do Stack em inglês](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260868/mvc5asp-net4-5-2-redirecttoaction-doesnt-return-in-one-case)